# Can't update the codes on the eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am coding jsp.
write some codes on the eclipse. then the page doesn't change at all to refresh the broswer .
I must be wating for a few seconds .
why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you make some changes to jsp file, eclipse need redeploy it into tomcat,and tomcat need to compile jsp file into servlet class internally,so this procedure need a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

enable auto deploy in your tomcat.
to do so follow the following steps.

Go to: Window/Show View/Servers
Double-click on the server that you associated with Eclipse
On the right-hand side, should be a collapsed menu titled "Publishing"
Expand the menu and you will see the radio buttons with the various auto-deploy options. check it so that it will work